# How to handle EULA pop-up window that appears only on first login?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to Selenium. The web interface of our product pops up a EULA agreement which the user has to scroll down and accept before proceeding. This happens ONLY on initial login using that browser for that user.

I looked at the Selenium API but I am unable to figure out which one to use and how to use it.

Would much appreciate any suggestions in this regard.

I have played around with the IDE for Chrome but even over there I don't see anything that I can use for this. I am aware there is an 'if' command but I don't know how to use it to do something like:

if EULA-pops-up:
   Scroll down and click 'accept'

proceed with rest of test.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  It will be to your benefit to complete your [tour] and check out [ask].  Namely, your question should provide specific code in a [mcve] to help us help you, as it stands it is too broad.  In any case, in Python it is [easier to ask for forgiveness](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp), so you can build a code to specifically handle the EULA and wrap it around `try... except...` block.  In which even if the EULA doesn't show up, it won't block the rest of your code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "which one to use"? The options you are trying to decide between aren't clear to me.

Comment: You've tagged your question with python - share your code tries up until know, the community will help you finish it - it's an easy enough task. Also add the relevant html of the popup, to get its specific elements.

Answer (score 0):

You may disable the EULA if that is an option for you, I am sure there is a way to do it in registries as well :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application there should be a file called master_preferences.

Open the file and setting:

require_eula to false

Comment: I think OP is asking about an EULA pop up in their product, not Chrome itself.